# Configuring XAMPP and "PHP Tools for Visual Studio"

Tags: php, visual-studio, xampp, visual-studio-2012

I am using XAMPP and the "PHP Tools for Visual Studio" extension in order to code in PHP. I already configured XAMPP to use xDebug and mod_rewrite. The web site looks OK when I copy everything into `C:\xampp\htdocs`. But when I start the solution from Visual Studio (2012) I get Error 310 (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS).

The path which is used then is "localhost:43950/". What's wrong with XAMPP/xDebug/PHPTools and how can I fix this?

If this is not enough information, I will provide more.

Comment: 'PHP Tools for Visual Studio' adds query parameter ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START to the start URL. Couldn't that be the cause of infinite redirection?